# Process individual worksheet using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am a tidyverse beginner and trying to process individual worksheets from the main excel file. The current script is able to iterate over each sheet but I am not able to pass individual sheet into my custom function. The sheet are unequal in number of rows and the program is trying to push all the sheets into a single data frame and failing. My goal is to process individual sheet and join with another table and perform independent operations.

Thank you so much for your comments and suggestions

```
Input = 'test.xlsx'

run_test <- function(x){
   newFrame <- data.frame(x) %>%
             select(ID, time, measure) %>%
             left_join(some_frame, by=c('ID'='subject'))
             ........
             ........
}


newFrame <- Input %>% 
excel_sheets() %>%  
set_names()  %>% 
map(read_excel, path = Input) %>%  run_test(.)
```

Comment: You may use `cat(names(x), "\n")`

Comment: You need a `purrr::reduce` for the `left_join` and a `purrr::map` for the select. You are currently pushing a list into your function. Then convert it to a `data.frame` first thing. So also remove the `data.frame` or again `purrr::map` over them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed you're joining with another `data.frame`. You just need to `map` over your list. Probably want the `purrr::reduce(left_join, ...)` if you want to make one final frame at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function as follows:

```r
run_test <- function(x,some_frame){
   newFrame <- map(x, data.frame) %>%
             # You are missing subject in your select. I added it.
             map(select, ID, time, measure, subject) %>%
             map(left_join, some_frame, by=c('ID'='subject'))
             ........
             ........
}
```